# Subprocess writing stdin and reading stdout python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

I am writing a script which would run a Linux command and write a string (up to EOL) to stdin and read a string (until EOL) from stdout. The easiest illustration would be `cat -` command:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['cat', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stringin="String of text\n"
p.stdin.write=(stringin)
stringout=p.stout.read()
print(stringout)
```

I aim to open the `cat -` process once and use it to write a string multiple times to its stdin every time getting a string from its stdout.

I googled quite a bit and a lot of recipes don't work, because the syntax is incompatible through different python versions (I use 3.4). That is my first python script from scratch and I find the python documentation to be quite confusing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with the process:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
s = Popen(['cat', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
input = b'hello!' # notice the input data are actually bytes and not text
output, errs = s.communicate(input)
```

To use unicode strings, you would need to `encode()` the input and `decode()` the output:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
s = Popen(['cat', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
input = 'España'
output, errs = s.communicate(input.encode())
output, errs = output.decode(), errs.decode()
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your solution Salva. 
Unfortunately `communicate()` closes the `cat -` process. I did not find any solution with `subprocess` to communicate with the `cat -` without having to open a new `cat -` for every call. I found an easy solution with [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) though:

```
import pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn('cat -')
p.setecho(False)

def echoback(stringin):
    p.sendline(stringin)
    echoback = p.readline()
    return echoback.decode();

i = 1
while (i < 11):
    print(echoback("Test no: "+str(i)))
    i = i + 1
```

In order to use `pexpect` Ubuntu users will have to install it through `pip`. If you wish to install it for python3.x, you will have to install pip3 (python3-pip) first from the Ubuntu repo.